# How to follow up on an interview

Tags: interviewing

I recently relocated to South Carolina,  I went on an interview with a hospital the Manager that interviewed me also had me do a peer to peer.  That was July 24th, on July 26th she called and offered me the position.

On July 27th the recruiter called and said the manager can't offer me the job HR has to. She went over my paper work and they ran a back round check,  I still haven't heard anything and I'm living in a hotel with my dtr.

Can't get an apartment without proof of employment.  Can I send them and email to follow up?

Comment: Could you update the question title?

Answer (score 0):

It can sometimes take a few days to run a background check. And sometimes it can take more than a few days if the company you're applying with is a little disorganized, which it sounds like this hospital might be.

I would definitely call the recruiter back. The worst case scenario is that they haven't even gotten around to running your background check, in which case calling them (and being polite and calm about the whole situation) might just motivate them to get a move on it.